# Euclidean correction in pairphist and poppr.amova causing significant phist

Tags: r

I am trying to calculate pairwise phist between islands with mitochondrial sequences. I noticed for a species I was getting an odd result when using pairphist() or poppr.amova() in R. There was hardly any difference in haplotypes and their frequencies between 2 populations yet it returned a significant phist. I went through your source code and found out this is a result of the euclidean correction that is in the code. If I just use pegas amova with a dist.dna() I get a phist and p-value that makes more sense and aren't significant at all. I was reading Excoffier et al. 1992 to understand the original creation of AMOVA and phist but I did not see why that euclidean correction needs to be added. Excoffier et al. state the distances should be a Euclidean metric δjk2 = (pj - pk)’W(pj - pk). But your function uses dist() which calculates √Σi(xi-yi)2.

I was wondering why the pairphist() and poppr.amova() functions in R use the euclidean correction when it doesn't seem to convert to the same type of formula as the original paper? I also was wondering why this euclidean correction could cause a very non-significant phist to convert to a significant one, especially when there is so little difference in haplotype frequencies.

I used pairPhiST with a dataframe of my seqs (sequences) and sites with each row as an individual and the following code

```
x <- as.list(fasta$seqs)
site <- fasta$sites
site <- as.factor(site)
x <- as.DNAbin(ape::as.alignment(x))
x <- as.dna(x)
pst <- pairPhiST(x, site, nperm=1000, negatives=TRUE, showprogbar=FALSE)
```

I get phist = 0.022 and p-values=0.034.

When I use pegas from amova and dist.dna with the following code

```
x <- as.list(fasta$seqs)
site <- fasta$sites
site <- as.factor(site)
x <- ape::as.alignment(x)
x <- as.DNAbin(x)
distances_1<-dist.dna(x, model="K80",as.matrix=TRUE)
result <- pegas::amova(distances_1 ~ site, nperm=1000)
```

I get phist=-0.013 and p-value=0.71

Since the haplotype frequencies are
Hawaii: Hap_1 = 27, Hap_2 = 1, Hap_3 = 2
Oahu: Hap_1 = 32, Hap_4 = 1
I think results from amova from pegas with dist.dna make more sense but I don't get why the results are so drastically different because of the euclidean correction in pairphist and poppr.amova.